# Sum convergence to $\ln 3-1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

I need to prove that a sum is equal to $$\ln{3}-1$$ and I got stuck at the following step
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\Big(\frac{1}{3n-1}+\frac{1}{3n}+\frac{1}{3n+1}-\frac{1}{n}\Big)$$

I think I should get to a telescopic form from now on, but the things I tried didnt work, so maybe not.

Comment: This is a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :**

$$\frac{1}{3n-1}+\frac{1}{3n}+\frac{1}{3n+1}-\color{blue}{\frac{3}{3n}}$$

$$\frac{1}{3n-1}+\frac{1}{3n+1}-\frac{2}{3n}$$

$$\frac{1}{3n-1}+\frac{1}{3n+1}-\frac{1}{3n}-\frac{1}{3n}$$

$$\Big(\frac{1}{3n+1}-\frac{1}{3n}\Big)-\Big(\frac{1}{3n}-\frac{1}{3n-1}\Big)$$

Answer (score 2):

@cosmo5's tip lets us write the sum as $\sum_{n\ge1}\int_0^1x^{3n-2}(1-2x+x^2)dx$, which by the dominated convergence theorem is$$\int_0^1\frac{x(1-x)^2}{1-x^3}dx=\int_0^1\left(\frac{1+2x}{1+x+x^2}-1\right)dx=\left[\ln(1+x+x^2)-x\right]_0^1=\ln3-1.$$